# Settings Keep Changing back

Tags: settings

The settings keep going back to factory settings either when the battery is low OR I turn off the phone.  For example, calendar sync turns off and I have to turn it back on each time I want the calendar to sync.  The display goes to the least brightest settings and 15 seconds for screen time out and I have to go in and readjust the brightness and screen time out time.  It is really annoying.  When I took it to the Sprint store and asked them about it, of course, it wouldn't do it.

Comment: What you describe sounds like some "battery low" actions (the device switching to an energy-saving mode). Settings are *not* going back to "factory settings" (or all your account information would be gone as well). Do those settings restore themselves once the device is charged up again?

Answer (score -1):

When the battery is low, the phone will turnoff services/processes, like sync, to save energy. It may help if the phone is kept charged.